# How can i shoot my billiard ball to angle which i picked in spinbox

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-billiard

Here is my code simply i want to shoot my ball to direction that i picked from spinbox. I aim with arrow and hit ball with the button Kresli. I will be very grateful if someone can help me with it because there is nothing on internet in this tkinter python graphic.

```
import tkinter
import math
from tkinter import ttk
class Simulacia(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
     '''Nastavenie počiatočných vlastnosti a spúšťanie ďalších metód triedy'''
     super().__init__()
     self.title('Rovnomerný priamočiary pohyb')
     self.vytvorGUI()
     self.mainloop()
     self.posun_lopty()
     self.rotate()
    def vytvorGUI(self):
     '''Vytvorenie grafického rozhrania programu (GUI)'''
     self.uhol = tkinter.IntVar()
     tkinter.Button(self, text='Kresli', command=self.posun_lopty).grid(row=1, column=0)
     tkinter.Button(self, text='Ukonči', command=self.destroy).grid(row=1, column=3)
     tkinter.Button(self, text='Vymaž pozadie', command=self.vytvorGUI).grid(row=2, column=3)
     tkinter.Label(self, text = "Uhol=", width = 10).grid(row =2, column =0)
     self.platno = tkinter.Canvas(self, width=800, height=600, background='green')
     self.x = 150
     self.y= 300
     self.lopta = self.platno.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x+ 20, self.y + 20, fill="white")
     self.sipka = self.platno.create_line(160, 310, 280, 310, tags=("minute",), arrow="last")
     self.radius = 30
     self.platno.create_rectangle(3, 3, 800, 600, outline="brown", width=10)
     self.platno.create_oval(-self.radius, -self.radius, +self.radius, +self.radius, fill="black")  # VLAVO HORe
     self.platno.create_oval(-self.radius, 600 - self.radius, +self.radius, 600 + self.radius, fill="black")  # VLAVO DOLE
     self.platno.create_oval(800 - self.radius, 0 - self.radius, 800 + self.radius, 0 + self.radius, fill="black")  # Vpravo HORE
     self.platno.create_oval(800 - self.radius, 600 - self.radius, 800 + self.radius, 600 + self.radius, fill="black")  # Vpravo Dole
     self.platno.create_oval(400 - self.radius, -self.radius, 400 + self.radius, self.radius, fill="black")  # Hore
     self.platno.create_oval(400 - self.radius, 600 - self.radius, 400 + self.radius, 600 + self.radius, fill="black")  # Dole
     self.sb_minute = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=60, increment=1, width=4, command=self.rotate)
     self.sb_minute.grid(row=2, column=1)
     self.sb_minute.set(15)
     self.platno.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4)
     self.dx = 5
     self.dy = 0
    def rotate(self):
        self.size = 300
        # get the spinbox value
        self.m = int(self.sb_minute.get())
        # set the line coordinates for minute hand
        # moves 6 degrees per minute (360/60)
        self.degrees = self.m * 6
        # angle needs to be in radians
        self.angle = self.degrees * math.pi * 2 / 360
        # center coordinates cx, cy
        self.cx = 160
        self.cy = 310
        # find proper endpoint coordinates for the line
        self.x0 = self.cx + self.size * math.sin(self.angle) * 0.40
        self.y1 = self.cy - self.size * math.cos(self.angle) * 0.40
        self.platno.coords('minute', (self.cx, self.cy, self.x0, self.y1))


    def posun_lopty(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        self.platno.move(self.lopta, self.dx, self.dy)
        if self.y == 595:
            self.dx = +self.dx
            self.dy = -self.dy
        if self.y == 0:
            self.dx = self.dx
            self.dy = -self.dy
        if self.x == 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
            self.dy = self.dy
        if self.x == 795:
            self.dx = -self.dx
            self.dy = +self.dy
        text_lopticka = "Loptička spadla do diery. Hra skončila"
        if ((self.x <= self.radius) and (self.y <= self.radius)):  # Vlavo HOre
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        if ((self.x <= self.radius) and (self.y <= 600 - self.radius)):  # VLAVO DOLE
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        if ((self.x >= 800 - self.radius) and (self.y <= self.radius)):  # Vpravo HORE
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        if ((self.x >= 800 -self.radius) and (self.y >= 600 - self.radius)):  # Vpravo Dole
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        if ((self.x <= 400 + self.radius) and (self.y <= self.radius)):  # Hore
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
        if ((self.x >= 400 - self.radius) and (self.y >= 600 - self.radius)):  # Dole
            self.platno.create_text(400, 300, text=text_lopticka, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))
            self.platno.delete(self.lopta)
            self.platno.create_oval(400 - self.radius + 10, 600 - self.radius + 10, 400 + self.radius - 10, 600 + self.radius - 10, fill="white")
            return
        self.platno.update()
        self.platno.after(10, self.posun_lopty)
        print(self.x, self.y)

Simulacia()
```

I tried some get() methods from spinbox but it didnt work at all

Comment: Can u fix indentation?

Comment: Try now when there is a problem i will check it on PC

Comment: Very nice billiard. I see that u had problem when  changing line angle. The ball always  travelled same horizontal.

Comment: U don't needed line 87 because u have 2 duplicate create_oval.

Comment: or maybe spinbox is not very good for setting up angle some advice ?

Comment: I found solution problem. It is not spinbox problem. Ur biggest problem is line not the ball.. I will have to redo it.

Comment: yes i know line is a big problem there because it count 15 when is in 0 degree angle

Comment: Don't worry about spinbox and count. By looking at this self.platno.move(self.lopta, self.dx, self.dy). I was looking for dx and dy. When u used angle for line. Let say 17. Then line must touched the edge of board. u must know dy  location. So the ball will move to a specified location.